# Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in php

Tags: php

I have tried using diff for date that's already converted to string.  But I am getting:

> Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string @ **die($hour);**

here's the code:

```
        $signin  = $this->input->post('signin');
        $signout = $this->input->post('signout');
        $old_date           = $attdate; // returns Saturday, January 30 10 02:06:34
        $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
        $new_date           = date('m/d/Y', $old_date_timestamp);


        // CHANGING THE DATE FORMAT FOR DB UTILITY
        $new_date_changed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $new_date)));

            $sin  = new DateTime($new_date . $signin);
            $sout = new DateTime($new_date . $signout);
            $hour = $sin->diff($sout);
            $work = $hour->format('%H h %i m');
            die($hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable at $hour is not printable as a string.

Use `var_dump($hour); die;` to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the variable is not a sting but an object.

change

```
die($hour);
```

to:

```
die($work);
```

or:

```
die($hour->format('%H h %i m'));
```

depending on what you want to pass to die.

Object DateTimeInterval needs [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to provide you string